# What is the best way to use one org as a template for another org?

Tags: deployment, template, org

Purpose is to save time, I've been reading about Trailforce - templates created from one org for different customizable orgs (if I understand it right, but that seems like a complicated way with creating/linking all the TMO,TSO,LMO,LMA)... Is there a different solution to my question ?

Comment: Are you an end-user (customer) of Salesforce or an ISV?

Comment: ...and hot off the presses, you can clone some sandboxes in Winter '23: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_sandboxes_quick_clone.htm&type=5&release=240

Comment: @identigral ISV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of org you're creating. For Developer Edition and Scratch Orgs, you always start fresh from a default template. For Sandboxes, you can use [SandboxInfo](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/tooling_api_objects_sandboxinfo.htm) to create a Sandbox from any other Sandbox or the Production Org that is attached to the Sandbox to be created. SFDX can do this for you when you use `force:org:create`. The Trialforce templates are only for orgs that will be become standalone subscriber orgs if the client subscribes beyond the trial period.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but what would be option for me, if the purpose was to get around the expiration date on Partner Developer Org ?

Comment: @TomášJurina All non-paid orgs have an expiration by default. You can make the org [exempt from deletion](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_de_org_expiration.htm&type=5), such as registering a namespace or making the org a Dev Hub org.